# Can a python dataset span multiple lines

Tags: python, data-analysis

I've got a large data set (18,000 points), and I need to take every 10th data point.

I've tried to manually reduce it down to 1 line by deleting line breaks and inserting commas, but this is taking too long

```py
dataSet={23.1440352679
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.1207721286
23.0975076366
23.1207721286
23.0975076366
23.1207721286}
```

Here's the first 14 items in the data set

I expect every 10th datapoint to be saved and printed, but I can't get it to work because of the line breaks.

Comment: How is your data set stored? Is it in a text file, with newlines separating each number?

Comment: You just have to write python code to read your data as it is - not try to make your data valid Python code with a couple tweaks on the file. 

Post a few lines of how your file _is_, without any editing, and what are actually your needs from this data (printing every other 10th numbers does not sound super useful) then people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Python container can span multiple lines, as long as there are delimiters (i.e. commas). For instance, this is a completely valid way to express a list:

```py
mylist = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

Dictionaries can also be expressed on multiple lines, e.g.

```py
mydict = {
    "zero": 0,
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3
}
```

However, you certainly shouldn't be converting a file of data points delimited by newlines manually! Python can handle the job. If memory is a concern, we can read line-by-line and only append the relevant data points to the list. The `str` method we use here to remove newlines is `rstrip()`, and for good measure we should convert the resulting string to an integer because I assume that's how you'll use the data points. In this example, I use "test.txt" as the name of your data points file.

```py
data = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i % 10 == 9:
            data.append(int(line.rstrip()))
```

If memory is not a concern, we have a different and potentially faster (although I did not time this) method:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = [int(lines[i].rstrip()) for i in range(9, len(lines), 10)]
```

If "every 10th point" means to go 0, 10, 20, etc. instead of 9, 19, 29, etc., then we just have to change `9` to `0`!